# Azure Event Data received through Service Bus Explorer is in hex format

Tags: python, azure, azureservicebus, qpid, azure-eventhub

I'm using Qpid-proton python example script(send.py) to send data to Azure Event Hub. To check that, I use Service Bus Explorer 2.6.1.0. The data sent using the python script is displayed as Hex values in Service Bus Explorer and not as what I send. But receiving the same using Qpid's recv.py gives expected result. So, is this an issue?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
# or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
# distributed with this work for additional information
# regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
# to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
# "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
# with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#   http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
# software distributed under the License is distributed on an
# "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
# KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
# specific language governing permissions and limitations
# under the License.
#
from __future__ import print_function
import sys, optparse
from proton import *

parser = optparse.OptionParser(usage="usage: %prog [options] <msg_1> ... <msg_n>",
                               description="simple message sender")
parser.add_option("-a", "--address", default="amqp://0.0.0.0",
                  help="address: //<domain>[/<name>] (default %default)")

opts, args = parser.parse_args()
if not args:
  args = ["Hello World!"]

mng = Messenger()
mng.start()

msg = Message()
for m in args:
  msg.address = opts.address
  msg.body = unicode(m)
  mng.put(msg)

mng.send()
print("sent:", ", ".join(args))

mng.stop()
```

**Send syntax**: $ python send.py -a [address] "Hello world"

I've also tried sending data using Azure python SDK. That sample data is received correctly in Service Bus Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce this issue using qpid-proton python to send messages into EventHub , but failed.

Then I sent messages by using Azure Python SDK, and received them thru Service Bus Explorer, but those event data was not displayed as Hex format. I think the issue seems to be caused by using qpid-proton python to serialize event data in character coding.  You need to use "UTF-8" instead of Unicode. In Python2, the UTF-8 string used prefix 'u' at the front of string, such as `u"Hello World!"`.